# Slim POST method doesn't post into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, rest, slim

I'm having rather weird problem. I'm getting no errors, console messages and everything is coming back as a 200 status therefore.

Using Slim framework to POST data into my database. When I access already existing data via urli everything is there so it works fine but it just doesn't POST it into MySQL. It does however put the data entered into ULR. Can someone indicate changes or where I'm going with this?

PS. don't be alarmed by password not being hashed this is not a live project.

Index.php snippet:

```
>           
>     <form class="form-horizontal" name="register_form" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
>     
>     <div class="form-group">
>         <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
>               </div>
>     </div></br>
>     <div class="form-group">
>           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
>               </div>
>     </div></br>
>     <div class="form-group">
>           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="date"  id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth DD/MM/YYYY">
>             </div>
>     </div></br>
>         
>     <div class="form-group">
>           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="school" name="school" placeholder="Enter School Name">
>               </div>
>     </div></br>
>         
>     <div class="form-group">
>           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="username" name="username" placeholder="Choose Username">
>               </div>
>       </div></br>
>         
>     <div class="form-group">
>           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
>       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
>       <input class="form-control" type="password"  id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Choose Password">
>               </div>
>             </div></br>   
>     
>     <div class="form-group">
>            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
>         
>            <button id="register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
>     </div></br>
>         
>             </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require 'Slim\Slim.php';
        \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
        use Slim\Slim;
        $app= new Slim();
        $app->get('/users','getUsers');
        $app->post('/users','addUser');
        $app->run(); 

// Adding a user = for registration process 
    function addUser(){
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $user = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(fname, lname, dob, school, username, pass) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :dob, :school, :username, :pass)";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("fname",$user->fname);
        $stmt->bindParam("lname",$user->lname);
        $stmt->bindParam("dob",$user->dob);
        $stmt->bindParam("school",$user->school);
        $stmt->bindParam("username",$user->username);
        $stmt->bindParam("pass",$user->pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user->UserID=$db->lastInsertID();
        $db = null;
        responseJson(json_encode($user),201);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        responseJson('{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}', 500);
    }
  }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
    var users=new users($("#fname").val(),
                        $("#lname").val(),
                        $("#dob").val(),
                        $("#school").val(),
                        $("#username").val(),
                        $("#pass").val());
    $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     dataType:"json",
     url:"api.php/users",
     data:JSON.stringify(users),
     success: showResponse,
     error: showError
        });    
    });
});

function users(fname, lname, dob, school, username, pass){
this.fname=fname;
this.lname=lname;
this.dob=dob;
this.school=school;
this.username=username;
this.pass=pass;
}

function showResponse(responseData){
console.log(responseData);
    }
function showError(){
alert("Sorry Kasia, but something went wrong. Fix it!")
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the problem is that `showResponse()` and `showError()` are defined as functions, rather than on `.ready()`. Do you get the alerts to trigger if you move them inside the AJAX itself?

Comment: No to be honest, these are sitting there but appear as not doing anything.

Comment: I'm alarmed by the password not being hashed. That's like leaving bare, live wires on the floor. It's basically [one line of code to fix with `password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) so there's really no excuse.

Comment: I agree that you should always hash your passwords even in a local environment. Working locally is a **very** common excuse to not has passwords, though if you do things right locally, you'll have no worries when you move to production :)

Comment: Friendly advice: you don't need those `users` variable and function. You can simply use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to pass your form data into the request. You would do something like `data: $(this ).closest('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

users is a function not an object, I think you are better of dropping the function and doing it inline in  the register click..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){

    var users={};
    users.fname=$("#fname").val();
    users.lname=$("#lname").val();
    users.dob=$("#dob").val();
    users.school=$("#school").val();
    users.username=$("#username").val();
    users.pass=$("#pass").val();

     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         dataType:"json",
         url:"api.php/users",
         data:JSON.stringify(users),
         success: showResponse,
         error: showError
            });    
        });
    });
```